# JPA transaction rollback is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, jta

Hi all 
   I have done an application configuration using hybernate + JPA ,and atomikos for XA transcation management and spring 3.0 and mysql is my backend,here every thing is working fine however insert operation, when exception is throwing the transcation should rollback,but it is not happening!!
   here is a small flow for our application, in our manager level we are  calling the businesss (here we are using Spring IOC)
 my

```
Manager.java        
        insertuser()
         {
         //here we are getting transcation support from spring.

          business.insertuser();
         }
```

business.java we are using one method insertuser()

```
insertuser()
  {
    Tauser taUser=new Tauser();
    taUser.setUsername("Maya");
    taUser.setPassword("*****")       
    Dao.insertDetails(taUser);
    throw new NullPointerException("checking transcation management"); 
    // because  of this exception throwing,it should rollback right,
    but its not happening.The property's are commiting in to the table.

 }
```

and our dao.java class we are using one method insertuser(Object entity)

```
 void insertDetails(Object entity)
       {
        this.getJpaTemplate().persist(entity);       
       }
```

and our     orm.xml

```
       <entity class="TaUser" name="TaUser">
<table name="ta_user" />
<attributes>
    <id name="userId">
        <column name="USER_ID" />
        <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>
    <basic name="userName">
        <column name="USER_NAME" length="50" />
    </basic>   
    </attributes>
```

and my persistence.xml file is

```
<persistence-unit name="shop" transaction-type="JTA">
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/shobWeb</jta-data-source>
           <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
           <class>TaUser</class>
           ---------
           ---------
           ---------
           <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" 
            value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup"/>
            </properties>     
    </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

and i configured my jndi in  application/meta_inf/context.xml

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/shobWeb" auth="Container"  
                      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
                      user="root"
                      password="root"  
                      type="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"   
                      factory="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSourceFactory" 
                      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shobWebSample"
                      explicitUrl="true" 
                      pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection="true" 
                      ></Resource>
```

and my config file is config.xml

```
<beans:bean id="Manager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="transactionManager">
        <beans:ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="target">
        <beans:ref local=" ManagerTarget" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="transactionAttributes">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ManagerTarget"
    class="Manager">
    <beans:property name="Business" ref="Business" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="Business" class="PaymentsBusiness">
    <beans:property name="Dao" ref=" Dao" />             
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="Dao"
    class=" Dao">
    <beans:property name="jpaTemplate">
        <beans:ref bean="jpaTemplate" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory">
        <beans:ref bean="entityManagerFactory" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="shop" />
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" /> 
         </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
        <bean:value>classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

where is the issue? Actually when i am trying to update some property in table then transcation is working fine (rollback and commit is  happening ),but when i am trying to do insert operation rollback is not happening.

Comment: Can you provide more of your actual code (with any company-specific stuff removed of course)? Seems like the transaction is being closed and committed after your call to the DAO, which is clearly not what you're trying to do.

Comment: More code will help. Especially how you are handling transaction boundaries? Also is there a specific reason to use orm.xml. Cannot you use annotation?

Comment: Impossible to say what's going on without any logs. Spring transactions outputs a lot of logging information in debug mode. Add `log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG` to your log4j config (or the equivalent to whatever you're using for logging), and see if the transactions are actually being used. This is your best option to debug that kind of stuff. If you still have trouble, update your post with the information. (By the way, you can edit your post to add information instead of posting it as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The more I look at this, the more confused it looks.

First, how does the AOP config relate to your actual methods? The way it is configured, it will only create transactions around methods starting with "save" or "remove", and read-only transactions around everything else. Your method is called `insertDetails`, so that won't work.

Second, do you have a Spring `PlatformTransactionManager` configured? I don't see the configuration.

Third: Looks like you're using the default package for your classes, but defined the pointcut for classes in a package `com.live.webAppl`. Is that where your classes really are?

Fourth: Is there an open transaction at the point where the exception is thrown, and did the inserting method participate in that transaction? If not, then it cannot rollback. Use the debugger together with the log output to see where which transaction is created and if the insert method participates. Try raising Atomikos' log level to debug, too.

Fourth, are you stuck in a Java 1.4 codebase? Otherwise, go for [annotational transaction declaration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations). (A lot of the ways things are done in your config and code look a little dated.)

Fifth, the convention is to use all lowercase package names. Classes start with a capital letter, members and locals lowercase. This will help the readability of your code. (For example, `Dao.insertUser()` looks like a static method call to anyone who can read Java. Not good.)